# Extracting the variables names from a list of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider two series which are attributes of a class instance xyz, and a list containing them:

For the sake of reproducing the problem, imagine s1 and s2 are:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

list= [xyz.s1, xyz.s2]
```

Given the list, how can I extract the series' names 's1' and 's2'?

I tried something like:

```
series_names = [str(x) for x in list]
```

But it did not work; it tried to convert the series' values into string, instead of the series' names.

Also,

```
series_names = [x.name for x in list]
```

led to:

```
series_names = ['xyz', 'xyz']
```

Desired output:

```
series_names = ['s1', 's2']
```

Comment: You cannot, generally. objects have no knowledge of the variables that reference them. More importantly, **why would you ever need this?**

Comment: Also, if I did `x = SomeType()` then `y = x`, what would the name of the object be? It is being referenced by *two different names*.

Comment: What if I did `x = [SomeType()]` and can access the instance using `x[0]`. What is the name of my instance?

Comment: s1 and s2 are attributes of a class instance, such as 'xyz.' If I do series_names = [x.name for x in list], what I get is [xyz, xyz]. You see? It retrieves the name of the class these attributes belong to. I need the name of the attributes themselves. I have a code that creates a data frame from series s1 and s2. I need 's1' and 's2' to use as dataframe column names. So, there is absolutely no way to extract ['s1' , 's2'] from [s1, s2]?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep the names for some reason, keep your data in a dictionary instead of a list.

```
series = {
    's1': pd.Series(np.random.rand(10)),
    's2': pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
}

series_names = [x for x in series] # ['s1', 's2']
```

Comment: The point is that I do not wish to manually type `'s1'` and `'s2'.`
Given `[s1, s2]`, I want Python to get me `['s1', 's2']`

Comment: When would you need to type them?  You can extract them again from the list by index or by iterating over it.  The only reason to keep the names is if you want to print them, in which case put your series in a dictionary or in the list as a tuple with the name.

Comment: Well, you created the `series` by manually typing 's1' and 's2', right? How would you get to the `['s1', 's2']` output if instead you created the series by `series = [s1, s2]`

Comment: I think the confusion is because I don't know why you want the ['s1','s2'] output.  What are you using that for?

Comment: Sorry for insufficient clarity. I was trying to simplify the question.

S1 and s2 are attributes of a class instance XYZ. They are both pandas series. I create a `list=[xyz.s1, xyz.s2]`, then feed it into a function that creates a data frame out of the series inside the list, and then sets the names of the series as the data frame's column names. In this case, we will should a data frame with columns 's1' and 's2'. Initially I thought I can create something like `column_names = [x.name for x in list]`. But the result of this turned out to be ['xyz', 'xyz'], and not ['s1', 's2'].

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with the `globals` function:

```
>>> s1 = 'a'
>>> s2 = 'b'
>>> globals()
{..., 's1': 'a', 's2': 'b'}
```

So you could do:

```
def extract_name(value):
    for k, v in globals().items():
        if v is value:
            yield k
```

This makes a generator, so that if two variables refer to the same object, it captures all the possible names:

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> a = A()
>>> b = a
>>> list(extract_name(a))
['a', 'b']
```

So, you could do:

```
>>> l = [s1, s2]
>>> [next(extract_name(v)) for v in l]
['s1', 's2']
```

(The use of `next` is to get the name out of the generator.)

Comment: It gives `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

Comment: @Saeed Sorry, fixed. It was the use of `==` instead of `is`.

Comment: Thanks, it works for these two series. I tried it with two other longer series of `pandas.core.series.Series type and it says: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<ipython-input-653-76270f1839e>", line 1, in <module>    [next(extract_name(v)) for v in vector]  File "<ipython-input-653-876270f1839e>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    [next(extract_name(v)) for v in vector] 
StopIteration`

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. One reason could be that the variables are locally defined; try using `locals()` instead of `globals()` in the function. Another is that the behavior could be differently defined in the ipython kernel. Try putting the code into a program and see how that runs.